# How to deploy report and dashboard folders with sharing to non scratch orgs

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, reports-folder

Can deploy dashboard and report folders using push:pull to scratch orgs, but when using source:deploy to a non scratch org getting "Error parsing flie Element (path to folder file meta.xml) on all folders. Enhanced folder sharing is on in target org.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DashboardFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>View</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>ProviderOne</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>Role</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
    <name>Addresses</name>
</DashboardFolder>
```

Do we have to convert or do something special with reports and dashboard folders between scratch and non-scratch orgs?
Cross posted in Salesforce DX Partner Forum.

Comment: did you ever get a response to this on the DX Partner forum?

Comment: No and we haven't revisited it really since this, will probably try again in 2-4 weeks.